# How to repeat the rows in a table

Tags: r

I have two tables.

Table1:

```
+-----+--------+-------------+
| Key | region | region_name |
+-----+--------+-------------+
| ABC | NT     | NORTH       |
| ABC | ST     | SOUTH       |
| XYZ | NT     | NORTH       |
| XYZ | ST     | SOUTH       |
| DEF | ST     | SOUTH       |
+-----+--------+-------------+
```

Table2:

```
+-----+-------+------+--------+
| KEY | Sales | cost | profit |
+-----+-------+------+--------+
| ABC |   130 |  100 |     30 |
| XYZ |   120 |   95 |     25 |
| DEF |   110 |   90 |     20 |
+-----+-------+------+--------+
```

I want the final output be like below.

```
+-----+-------+------+--------+--------+-------------+
| KEY | Sales | cost | profit | region | region_name |
+-----+-------+------+--------+--------+-------------+
| ABC |   130 |  100 |     30 | NT     | NORTH       |
| ABC |   130 |  100 |     30 | ST     | SOUTH       |
| XYZ |   120 |   95 |     25 | NT     | NORTH       |
| XYZ |   120 |   95 |     25 | ST     | SOUTH       |
| DEF |   110 |   90 |     20 | ST     | SOUTH       |
+-----+-------+------+--------+--------+-------------+
```

Thanks in advance..!

Comment: Hi I pasted the tables, not sure why we are getting like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `left_join`

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(df1, df2, by = 'Key')
```

---

Or with `merge` in `base R`

```
merge(df1, df2, by = 'Key', all.x = TRUE)
```

Comment: Hi @akrun, I am getting the error while executing the merge statement. With left_join, r studio is getting stuck.

Comment: @avinash0513. with the example you showed, it is working fine for me

Comment: @avinash0513 if you don't tell us the error you got, it is very difficult to understand the issue.

Comment: hi @akrun, Error in merge.data.table(raw_data, mapping_file, by = "Key", all.x = TRUE) : 
  Elements listed in `by` must be valid column names in x and y. This is the message

Comment: Hi @akrun, it's working now. The challenge is with the values in the data sets I have. Thank you..!